# Python format strings: 'Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value'

Tags: python, string-formatting, mysql-python

I format a string `sql` with `sid` (NOTE: the type of `sid` is `str`)

```
sid = "34"  #type(sid) is string, like 34, 34s
sql = '''SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sid={sid}'''.format(sid=sid)
```

The result of `print sql` is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sid=34
```

which is out of my expection (**`34` vs `"34"`**):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sid="34"
```

While using this `sql` as a parameter of `cur.execute(sql)`, encounter the following error, leading to the error output.

```
Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '88s'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to wrap your value in quotes, you can add that in your string and make sure to escape your `"` characters with `\`

```
>>> 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sid=\"{sid}\"'.format(sid=sid)
'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sid="34"'
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sid="{sid}"` works in triple-quoted strings `'''` because double-quotes `"` is unescaped?

Comment: If you use triple quotes, no you do not need to escape the double quotes (though if you do it won't cause a problem)

Comment: there is one more concise solution, use the conversion flag `!r`: `'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sid={sid!r}'.format(sid=sid)`

Answer (score 0):

One more concise solution, use the conversion flag **[!r](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)**:

```
>>> sid = "34"
>>> sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sid={sid!r}'.format(sid=sid)
>>> sql
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE sid='34'"
```

There are two conversion flags in `str.format()`:

- `!s` calls `str()` on the value
- `!r` calls `repr()` on the value